# Eigenvalues of the product of two symmetric matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

This is mostly a reference request, as this must be well-known!

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric matrices, one of which is positive definite. Then it is easy to see that the product $AB$ (or $BA$, which has the same eigenvalues) is similar to a symmetric matrix, so has real eigenvalues. Take the vectors of eigenvalues of $A$ and of $B$, sorted in decreasing order, and let their componentwise product be $ab$. What is known about the relationship (e.g., inequalities) between $ab$ and the vector of eigenvalues of the product $AB$ (also taken in decreasing order)?

Some experimentation gives the conjecture that there is a majorization order between them, for instance. This must be well-known!

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but I assume you're familiar with von Neumann's trace inequality, Richter's corresponding lower bound and L. Mirsky's elementary proofs of these.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/47830/7003

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are the results that you are probably looking for.

The first one is for positive definite matrices only (the theorem cited below fixes a typo in the original, in that the correct version uses $\prec_w$ instead of $\prec$).

> **Theorem** (Prob.III.6.14; Matrix Analysis, Bhatia 1997). Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian positive definite. Let $\lambda^\downarrow(X)$ denote the vector of eigenvalues of $X$ in decreasing order; define $\lambda^\uparrow(X)$ likewise. Then, 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\uparrow(B) \prec_w \lambda(AB) \prec_w \lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\downarrow(B),
> \end{equation*}

where $x \cdot y := (x_1y_1,\ldots ,x_ny_n)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$  and $\prec_w$ is the [weak majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) preorder.

However, when dealing with matrix products, it is more natural to consider singular values rather than eigenvalues.

> Therefore, the relation that you might be looking for is the *log-majorization*
>   \begin{equation*}
> \log \sigma^\downarrow(A) + \log\sigma^\uparrow(B) \prec \log\sigma(AB) \prec \log\sigma^\downarrow(A) + \log\sigma^\downarrow(B),
> \end{equation*}
>   where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary matrices, and $\sigma(\cdot)$ denotes the singular value map.

**Reference**

1. R. Bhatia. *Matrix Analysis*. Springer, GTM 169. 1997.

Comment: What is $\lambda(AB)$? You only defined $\lambda^\uparrow$ and $\lambda^\downarrow$.

Comment: @DavidE.Roberson $\lambda(AB)$ is the vector whose elements are the eigenvalues of $AB$. I edited the question and added the definitions of $\cdot$ and $\prec$ so that the inequality should be more clearer now.

Comment: @shamisen but eigenvalues in what order?

Comment: @MichałMasny It does not matter what order because the majorization preorder does not depend on order.

By the way, does anyone know a direct proof of the first result? In Bhatia's book it proves the second result which is stronger, but I would like to know if there is a somewhat easier direct proof of the first result.

Comment: Can somebody please point out when does the equality hold true, in both the lower bound and upper bound part separately, in the "weak majorization preorder's" of theorem 1 above?

Answer (score 0):

> Let $A,B$ be $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices whose eigen values are non-negatives. Let $
>  \lambda_1(X) \geq \lambda_2(X) \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n(X)$ denote
> ordered eigenvalues of $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix $X$.
>
> Then, $\lambda_j(AB) \leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_{j-i+1}(B),$
> for any $i \leq j$.

Proof.
Let $a_i,b_i$ and $c_i$ be the unitary eigenvectors of $A,B$ and $A+B$, respectively. Namely, $A a_i = \lambda_i(A)a_i$ and so on.

Let $V_a,V_b$ and $V_c$ are vector spaces spanned by the vectors $\{a_i,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_{j-i+1},...,b_n\}$ and $\{c_1,...,c_j\}$,  respectively. Then, $V_a \cap V_b \cap V_c \neq 0$. In fact, for arbitrary vector spaces $X,Y$, we can say $\dim (X \cap Y) = \dim(X)+\dim(X) -\dim(X+Y )$ and using this twice, it follows that

$\dim(V_a \cap V_b \cap V_c ) =\dim(V_a \cap( V_b \cap V_c)  )$

$=\dim(V_a)  + \dim( V_b \cap V_c)  - \dim(V_a + ( V_b \cap V_c))  $

$=\dim(V_a)  + \dim( V_b ) + \dim( V_c) -   \dim( V_b +V_c) - \dim(V_a + ( V_b \cap V_c))  $

$\geq\dim(V_a)  + \dim( V_b ) + \dim( V_c) -  n -n $

$= (n-i+1)  + (n-j+i-1)+1 + j -  n -n$

$= 1,$

and thus there is a nonzero unit vector  $x \in V_a \cap V_b \cap V_c.$

Because $x \in V_c$, we can write $x= \sum_{\nu =1}^j x^\nu c_\nu$ and then,

$<x,(AB)x>= <  \sum_{\nu =1}^j x^\nu c_\nu   , (AB) \sum_{\nu =1}^j x^\nu c_\nu   >$

$ = <  \sum_{\nu =1}^j x^\nu c_\nu   , \sum_{\nu =1}^j x^\nu  \lambda_\nu(AB)c_\nu   >$

$ =    \sum_{\nu =1}^j | x^\nu |^2    \lambda_\nu(AB)$

$ \geq  \sum_{\nu =1}^j | x^\nu |^2    \lambda_j(AB)$

$ =   \lambda_j(AB) \cdots \cdots \cdots (1).$

Similarly, because $x \in V_a$, we can write $x= \sum_{\nu =i}^n x^\nu a_\nu$ and then,

$<x,Ax>= <  \sum_{\nu =i}^n x^\nu a_\nu , A\sum_{\nu =i}^n x^\nu a_\nu   >$

$ = <  \sum_{\nu =i}^n x^\nu a_\nu , A\sum_{\nu =i}^n x^\nu a_\nu   >$

$ =    \sum_{\nu =i}^n | x^\nu |^2    \lambda_\nu(A )$

$ \leq  \sum_{\nu =i}^j | x^\nu |^2    \lambda_i(A )$

$ =   \lambda_i(A )  \cdots \cdots \cdots (2).$

Similarly,
$<x,Bx> \leq  \lambda_{j-i+1}(B ) \cdots \cdots \cdots (3).$

Combining the inequalities (1),(2),(3) and Cauchy Schwartz inequality, we get

$\lambda_j(AB) \leq <x,(AB)x> \leq  |<A^*x , Bx>| \leq  |A^*x| \dot | Bx| \leq    \lambda_i(A )  \lambda_{j-i+1}(B ). $

This completes the proof.

Comment: This can not possibly be true. Take two 2x2 diagonal matrices with eigenvalues (1,K) for large K.

Comment: I read the proof and I noticed that there is a typo in the statement. So, I replaced  $\lambda_i(AB) \leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_{j-i+1}(B)$ with $\lambda_j(AB) \leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_{j-i+1}(B).$  If it is still incorrect, please let me know.