# Existence of a matrix product from its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Let A and B be two positive definite, real, symmetric matrices. The eigenvalues of A, B and AB, denoted by $\lambda(X)$, obey the relation (from [Bhatia](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices/106199#106199?newreg=f1980dddf98c4cc98efa4879e2e7953f)):
$$
\lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\uparrow(B) \prec \lambda(AB) \prec \lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\downarrow(B)
$$
where $\downarrow$ indicates decreasing order, $\uparrow$ increasing order, $x \cdot y := (x_1y_1,\ldots ,x_ny_n)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$  and $\prec$ is the [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) preorder.

My question is, for a given set of eigenvalues $\lambda(A),\, \lambda(B)$ and $\lambda(AB)$  which satisfies the above, does there necessarily exist an A and B such that they and AB have the desired eigenvalues?

I've found plenty of material on similar inequalities, but nothing that states if every solution of the inequalities can be realised.

Comment: How about $A$ is the identity matrix, and $B$ is the diagonal matrix with the given eigenvalues?  Can you make your question a bit more precise and generally understandable?

Comment: Reworded the question to, hopefully, be clearer.

Comment: If I understand everything correctly, just define $A$ and $B$ to be diagonal matrices, where the eigenvalues are placed in descending order.  Can you confirm this is what you are asking about?  If so it is really off topic for this site.

Comment: Let's take an explicit example. Let $\lambda(A)=(2,1)$, $\lambda(B)=(3,1)$, and $\lambda(AB)=(4,1.5)$. It's easy to check that these numbers satisfy the inequality in the question. Clearly, taking A and B to be diagonal matrices, however, does not work. 
In this case, a solution is to take $$ A = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{5}{4} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & \frac{7}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and $$B = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$.

Comment: Thanks!  This clarifies things immensely.  Would you mind adding this example to the question?

Comment: I am probably only proving how stupid I am at this point, but how does taking $A$ and $B$ to be diagonal matrices above not invalidate the theorem?

Comment: I guess I am maybe more confused than I thought.  If $\lambda(A)$ is only a set (not an ordered set), what does $\prec$ mean here?

Comment: @StevenGubkin $\prec$ means the [majorization preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) and $x \cdot y := (x_1 y_1, \ldots, x_n y_n)$.

Comment: @Ben I don't think this example is correct, since $\lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\uparrow(B) = (2,3)$,$\lambda(AB) = (4, 1.5)$ and hence $2+3 \ne 4 + 1.5$.

Comment: I've checked the example above: the eigenvalues of A, B and AB are definitely right. I do however agree with you Shamisen, something doesn't make sense. In fact, there is no reason in general that $\sum_i \lambda^\downarrow(A)_i \lambda^\uparrow(B)_i = \sum_i \lambda^\downarrow(A)_i \lambda^\downarrow(B)_i$ so it's not even necessarily true that $\lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\uparrow(B)\prec \lambda^\downarrow(A) \cdot \lambda^\downarrow(B)$. Ive looked through the textbook that first states this (Bhatia) and the only explanation I can find is that he means $\prec_w$ instead of $\prec$.