# Bound of the eigenvalues of a matrix product of two diagonal and one symmetric PSD matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

Let B be a positive diagonal matrix, and C a PSD symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\Lambda$, with $\lambda_i = {0,1}$. I'm trying to find a reference for the following bounds or similar

$B^{1\over 2}DB^{1\over 2} \preceq \Lambda B$

$DB \preceq \Lambda B$.

I've checked [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices/106199#106199?s=8cea4bc63aa8424ea8c781b70547fcf2) but they bound the eigenvalues according to the weak majorization order. Also, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/evaluating-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows a bound $\lambda_i(AB)\leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_i(B)$, where $\lambda_i(A)$ denotes the ith eigenvalue of A, but it is only for positive definite matrices.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $B^{1/2}DB^{1/2}$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $DB$, and you can treat positive semidefinite matrices using a limit argument. So you should be able to use the result on $\lambda_i(AB)$.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me what you mean with $\preceq \Lambda B$, since $\Lambda B$ may not be symmetric.

Comment: I mean that the eigenvalues of $DB$ are smaller than the eigenvalues of $D$, ie $\Lambda$, multiplied by $B$.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I normally associate that notation to the Loewner ordering, which is a stronger property.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with by using a limit argument. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Replace $C$ with $C+\varepsilon I$. Now it is posdef, and you can use that lemma. So the inequality holds for all $\varepsilon$, and you can let $\varepsilon \to 0$.